# Find integers/floats/strings in a string of text and put in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, array-map

I have a string and want split them in an array based on type. 
I can extract numbers and floats like below, but is not complete to my goal

```
 var arr = "this is a string 5.86 x10‘9/l 1.90 7.00"
   .match(/\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/g)
   .map(function (v) {return v;});

 console.log(arr);

 arr = [5.86, 10, 9, 1.9, 7]
```

I would like have even chunk of string type and mixed like "x10‘9/l":

```
 arr = ["this is a string", 5.86, "x10‘9/l", 1.9, 7]
```

can someone figure out?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. I think if you clarify the problem to yourself (and us, if needed), it will guide how you can go about solving this problem. Specifically: where do you split the input, and when do you cast pieces of the input to different types?

Comment: Jack this is for PRO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const result = [];

 const str = "this is a string 5.86 x10‘9/l 1.90 7.00";

 result.push(str.split(" ").reduce((acc, part) => isNaN(part) ? acc + " " + part : ((acc && result.push(acc)), result.push(+part), ""), ""));
```

Comment: nice solution but still empty parts of the array are there or they are untrimmed. a way to do the job in one piece?

Comment: @gael sure, but gets a bit more ugly :)

Comment: hey Jonas, it removes "0" and 0 from the output... can you guess why?

Comment: @gael oh right `acc && ` will also filter out 0 as its falsy. Might take `acc !== "" &&` instead ...

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
 var arr = [];
 var str = "this is a string 5.86 x10‘9/l 1.90 7.00";
 arr.push(str.split(" ").reduce((acc, part) => isNaN(part) ? acc + " " + part : (arr.push(acc.trim(), +part), ""), ""));

 var result = arr,
     len = arr.length, i;

 for(i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
     result[i] && result.push(result[i]);  // copy non-empty values to the end of the array
 }

 result.splice(0 , len);  // cut the array and leave only the non-empty values
 console.log(result);
```